# What does this OID identify? - Using MailKit to access POP3 on Gmail

Tags: mono, xamarin.android, ssl-certificate

1.2.840.113549.1.2.5

I have an exception in some Xamarin Android code whilst trying to access gmail through pop3 (see below).

This seems to be the code here...
 [mono / mcs / class / Mono.Security / Mono.Security.Cryptography / PKCS1.cs](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Cryptography/PKCS1.cs)

Obviously "1.2.840.113549.1.2.5" is not supported. What I want to know is what does this identify. A quick search in google throws up nothing. Is this a bug on the gmail side?

```
System.ArgumentException: certificate ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Unsupported hash algorithm: 1.2.840.113549.1.2.5
08-05 13:39:49.897 E/        (18362):   at Mono.Security.Cryptography.PKCS1.HashNameFromOid (System.String oid, Boolean throwOnError) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-05 13:39:49.897 E/        (18362):   at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate.VerifySignature (System.Security.Cryptography.RSA rsa) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-05 13:39:49.897 E/        (18362):   at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate.VerifySignature (System.Security.Cryptography.AsymmetricAlgorithm aa) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-05 13:39:49.897 E/        (18362):   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain.IsSignedWith (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 signed, System.Security.Cryptography.AsymmetricAlgorithm pubkey) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-05 13:39:49.897 E/        (18362):   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain.Process (Int32 n) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-05 13:39:49.897 E/        (18362):   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain.ValidateChain (X509ChainStatusFlags flag) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-05 13:39:49.897 E/        (18362):   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain.Build (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 certificate) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last known OID in the tree is [1.2.840.113549.1.2](http://oid-info.com/get/1.2.840.113549.1.2).

Your error occurs when a signature is being verified. Do you verify the signature manually?

The OID appears to be in some certificate. Could you trace what certificate it is and take a look inside using [ASN.1 editor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4910/ASN-Editor)? Try to find where the OID is. I suspect that it will be in the signature part of the certificate. Now take the certificate and try to open/verify it on different platform. It should fail in the same way. If so then the certificate was IMHO issued  incorrectly and you should report it to google or (better) the issuer of the certificate.

Comment: No, not verifying manually. This happened inside some code authenticating a POP3 connection to gmail using MimeKit from...https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit  Not sure how I would get the cert out manually.

Comment: You have source code of MimeKit. Take it, compile it with debug symbols, use this debug build in your project and set your debugger to stop on exception :). Then follow callstack to a point where you have this certificate available (if it is not available when the exception is thrown).

Comment: You mean I have to do actual debugging rather than just cutting and pasting from a SO post???  I'm Shocked! :-)

Comment: I'm giving you the answer tick because it is good guidance. This has stopped happening after I corrected some configuration where I was connecting to the wrong port on gmail.